# How strong can tidal forces get?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, tidal-effect

I am imagining a planet the size of Earth being in close proximity to something of high mass such as a gas giant or a star, but ultimately I'd be more interested in *how* to figure this out myself.

So (as it states in the title), I am trying to find out how strong, realistically [tidal forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) could be, before a planet is destroyed.

One way of stating this question would be: ignoring other factors, how close could the earth get to the sun before it would be destroyed by tidal forces? Would the tidal forces be strong enough to be noticed directly by anything on the surface?

I am honestly not sure which quantities are relevant. Is the important quantity the yield strength of rock? Or does the molten core make this slightly irrelevant?

My other guess would be that it has something to do with the gravitational binding energy. It seems like if the tidal potential energy was on the order of the gravitational binding energy, then bad things would happen, but that seems rather subjective. I guess it depends on what I mean by destroyed, but at least that is an upper bound though, right?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=tidal+roche+limit

Comment: @Qmechanic There seems to be some benefit in knowing what things are called. :)

Comment: $\uparrow$ True! :)